# Glass Mapper is not returning an Image Field

Tags: glass-mapper

I have a model that looks like this:

```
[Serializable]
[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{guid}", AutoMap =true)]
public class EventInfo : GlassBase
{

    public virtual string PageTitle { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    [SitecoreField("SmallTileImage")]
    public virtual Image SmallTileImage { get; set; }

}
```

I'm using this is my controller to return the item:

```
string query = string.Format("fast:{0}//*[@@templateid='{1}']", 
    eventfolder, eventTemplate);
var model = GetDataSourceItem<OtherEvents>();
model.RecentEvents = context.Query<EventInfo>(query)
     .Where(x => x.StartDate >= DateTime.Today).OrderBy(x => x.StartDate);
```

All the fields are being returned apart from the Image field, I've checked it's in web and master db.  Also if I do this:

```
foreach (var ev in Model.RecentEvents)
{
    var item = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(ev.Id);
    Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField imgField = ((Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField)item.Fields["SmallTileImage"]);
}
```

on my view then it returns the value as expected.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -4):

You need to create a Custom Search Index Field to get the url of your image. While Querying to Solr it will not return any complex Datatype like Image instead you need to create a custom Solr Index Field to get the image field url.

You could add a computed field. Here is John West's post about it. Below is a condensed example to get just the URL of the image.

Create a class that implements Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.IComputedIndexField.

```
public class ImageIndexField : IComputedIndexField
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string ReturnType { get; set; }

    public object ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(indexable, "indexable");
        var indexableItem = indexable as SitecoreIndexableItem;

        if (indexableItem == null)
        {
            Log.Warn(string.Format("{0} : unsupported IIndexable type : {1}", this, indexable.GetType()), this);
            return null;
        }

        ImageField img = indexableItem.Item.Fields["MyImageField"];

        return img == null || img.MediaItem == null ? null : MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(img.MediaItem);
    }
}
```

Then, add a config include with something like this:

```
<sitecore>
<contentSearch>
    <configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
        <defaultIndexConfiguration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndexConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
            <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
                <field fieldName="MyImageFieldUrl" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED">sc70.Search.ComputedFields.ImageUrlIndexField, sc70</field>
            </fields>
        </defaultIndexConfiguration>
    </configuration>
</contentSearch>
```

Note that the field name is hard coded above. I'm not sure if it is possible to pass that in as a parameter from the config. Sitecore seems to be creating separate classes for each of their computed fields and using inheritance to get reuse.

Please refer this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588900/sitecore-index-for-image-type?rq=1

Also refer this article : https://jockstothecore.com/media-indexing-approaches/

Comment: Why would you need a custom search index field? The OP isn't using an index to get any of the content. Its just a Fast Query (now that should also be fixed...), but there are no indexes involved or needed here.

Comment: yes, that's correct.  What should I use instead of Fast Query?